# Font-Awesome Icon stacking issue in safari

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm having this weird problem with my font awesome icons. I wanted my icons to have a round border. I don't want to use `border: 1px solid` because icon border will look blurry. I have achieved this smooth border by the "`stacking method`" of font-awesome as described [**here**](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#stacked.)

Since my font is 64px large, this `fa-circle-thin` icons border is too thick. To avoid that I used `box-shadow`.

> My problem is that my icon border is not uniform.

In chrome, border is a little thick at left side.(Somehow I can't replicate this issue in fiddle/snippet so which can be neglected.)

[image: Chrome]

but in safari, border is thick at right side.

[image]

How to get rid of this issue ? I don't want to use `-webkit-text-stroke` as it has limited browser support. Any help is much appreciated :)

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hwpobc93/)**

Here is my code.

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.social-block .fa {
    font-size: 64px;
}

span.fa-stack {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

.social-block .fa-stack-1x:before {
    font-size: 24px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 64px;
}
.social-block .fa-stack-1x{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 7px #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
}
.social-block a:hover .fa-stack-1x{
    box-shadow: none;
}
.social-block a:hover .fa-stack-1x:before {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    left: 7px;
    top: 7px;
    position: absolute;
}

.social-block .fa {
    color: #CC1E4A;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all ease .25s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .25s;
    -o-transition: all ease .25s;
    transition: all ease .25s;
    font-size: 64px;
}

.social-block a:hover .fa-circle-thin {
    background: none;
}
.social-block a:hover .fa-stack-1x:before {
    background: #CC1E4A;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.social-block a:hover .fa-stack-1x {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="social-block">
  <a href="#">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x"></i>
     </span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x"></i>
     </span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x"></i>
     </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: The uneven border thickness also occurs in Firefox too. I suggested an answer by using border-radius instead of stacking, and it looks pretty good, and no need to *hack* the pixels with absolute position. Choice is yours, you can start a bounty if you want to get more attentions.

Comment: @Pangloss I actually wanted a 1px thickness. But if I use border:1px solid, it will look blurry. ( common issue). I think this icon stacking issue don't have a fix. Going with border-radius method. thanks for helping.

Comment: I tweaked the code slightly, and added the info for multi-weight version of font awesome, all updated into the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the weight of the current Font Awesome icons, however the designer also created a commercial set of multi-weight icon fonts called **[Black Tie](http://blacktie.io/)**, which includes **light** font.

As a workaround, instead of stacked icons, I would suggest to just use the normal icons and draw the circles with `border-radius`. Keep it simple, and easy to update.

**[Jsfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qwob9t8p/)**

```css
.social-block a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #cc1e4a;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #cc1e4a;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  transition-property: color, box-shadow;
}
.social-block a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #cc1e4a;
  background-color: #cc1e4a;
  color: #fff;
}
.social-block .fa {
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 100%;
}
/* center icon vertically */
.social-block .fa:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* box-shadow white line fixes */
.social-block a:hover:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -3px; right: -3px;
  top: -3px; bottom: -3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid #cc1e4a;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="social-block">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index:-1;` to `.social-block .fa-stack-1x` class.

```
.social-block .fa-stack-1x {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 7px #fff;
    z-index:-1; // Add this
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px; 
}
```

eg:
https://jsfiddle.net/hwpobc93/14/

———————

**Updated:**

The circle has the thickness which font awesome applys by default:

If you wish to have more control you have to change a bit the css:

- Remove the border icon `<i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>`
- Add a before to create the border

New Exemple:

https://jsfiddle.net/hwpobc93/18/

Comment: z-index actually increased the border thickness. I want thin border. and should be uniform as decribed in the question.

Comment: The circle has the thickness which font awesome applys by default, see my post.